# "TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments" is the error I'm getting but I have answered all the arguments, what am I doing wrong

Tags: python-3.9

*I have answered all the arguments what am I doing wrong. I am also new at this so I could have made a very obvious error, thanks for your help.*

**error  message**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cogli\PycharmProjects\inkling\classses_pt2.py", line 4, in <module>
    stu = data(input("name, ") + input("major, ") + input("gpa, ") + input("is_on_probation "))
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'major', 'gpa', and 'is_on_probation'
```

**code**

```
from classes import data
#stu = data(input("name, " + "major, " + "gpa, " + "is_on_probation "))
stu = data(input("name, ") + input("major, ") + input("gpa, ") + input("is_on_probation "))
print(stu.name)
```

**import file**

```
class data:
    def __init__(self, name, major, gpa, is_on_probation):
        self.name=name
        self.major=major
        self.gpa=gpa
        self.is_on_probation=is_on_probation
```

**outcome**

```
name, ian
major, physics
gpa, 4.0
is_on_probation False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cogli\PycharmProjects\inkling\classses_pt2.py", line 4, in <module>
    stu = data(input("name, ") + input("major, ") + input("gpa, ") + input("is_on_probation "))
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'major', 'gpa', and 'is_on_probation'
```

I'm using python  3.9 to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`input("name, ") + input("major, ") + input("gpa, ") + input("is_on_probation ")` returns a single string because the `+` operator concatenates strings. In Python, the syntax to separate arguments to a function uses a comma, so you should do

```
stu = data(input("name, "), input("major, "), input("gpa, "), input("is_on_probation "))
```